# Error in inserting Multiple Rows Using Loop with one Button Save in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my Code for MODEL:

```
public function save_addition_enrollment(){


        foreach($employee as $employees)
        { 


                foreach($addition_type as $addtype)
                { 

                    if($_POST[$addtype->id."-".$employees->employee_id]){
                        $amount = $_POST[$addtype->id."-".$employees->employee_id] ;
                        $this->data = array(
                        'company_id'            => $this->input->post('company_id'),
                        'employee_id'           => $this->input->post('checkbox'),
                        'payroll_period_id'     => $this->input->post('pay_period'),
                        'other_addition_id'     => $addtype->id,
                        'amount'                => $amount,
                        'date'                  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                            );  
                        $this->db->insert('other_addition_enrollment',$this->data);
                        redirect(base_url().'app/payroll_other_addition_emp_enrollment/index',$this->data);
                    }           

                 }

        }

}
```

I cant insert multiple value of text box  i used loop but its not functioning can you tell what is the wrong in my code

This is my Code for VIEW:
code for view its too long i do screenshot image

[image]

output image of multiple row with 1 button Save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the spelling mistake in this field try like this:

```
$_POST["oa".$addtype->id."-".$employees->employee_id]
```

you have to passed foreach variable in like this:

```
public function save_addition_enrollment($employee){
```

and in controller like this:

```
$this->model->save_addition_enrollment($arrayofemployee);
```

Comment: $_POST["oa".$addtype->id."-".$employees->employee_id]

in the model?

Comment: yes. In the field name you have add "oa" and in model you dont.

Comment: after trying my foreach say 
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and
 Undefined variable: employee

Comment: you have to passed array to perform foreach. How it get $employee you have to passed it in function

Comment: yes i have that in my Controller and i use that foreach in view but in the model my foreach is not functioning

Comment: You passed the foreach array in parameter. then you able to get in model.

Comment: can you post here ?

Comment: Thank you sir but after i edit my code like your said i have an error says

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: app/payroll_other_addition_emp_enrollment_model.php

Line Number: 293

Comment: That means there no value you have getting that variable

Comment: yah your right but for now i change my code and my only error is 
Message:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Answer (score 0):

A small suggestion try using $this->db->insert_batch('other_addition_enrollment', $this->data);. Just to enhance the performance.